# URL submenu if primary menu is custom link wordpress

Tags: wordpress, menu, submenu

this is my situation in a wordpress menu :
[image]

Example 3 is a custom link, so the URL of submenu is

www.site.com/sub1 and not www.site.com/example3/sub1

www.site.com/sub2 and not www.site.com/example3/sub2

How to do?

Comment: Would you like to put a content on example3??

Comment: I don't understand...

Answer (score 0):

let me just post the answer here. Check out my demo site 
http://dev.blurbpad.com/21sthomeloans/

Then hover over About Us in the Menu, you will see two sub pages. Open both in separate tabs. I think what you want to happen is what I did in subpage 1 where it's not showing in the url the-company (like in sub page 2)

The only time it will say that in the URL is if you made the another page a parent of the sub page (in this case "about us"). If you just make the adjustments in appearance>menus in wordpress, and not make it a child of another page, then the URL will not be affected.

Comment: Ok. If that's the case, then just make the changes in Appearance > Menus and don't make the sub page a child of the Parent Page. If you are not familiar, I can help you with this if you like :)